# Drawing historical shipping routes?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I´m working on a project where I have to draw historical shipping routes of trade, whaling, etc. ships from the XIX century.

I´ve done some research and checked [Maritime route prediction avoiding land masses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67978/maritime-route-prediction-avoiding-land-masses) but I want to be sure that I am going in the right direction because I have to learn this tool from scratch:

- To draw the routes: I have mainly the origin and the destination point and sometimes intermediate harbours. I need a way to approximately draw from data as currents, winds, coastline and landmasses a route of how the vessels got from one place to other. I am currently learning postgis and postgresql. For my goal, is Pgrouting the most useful and simple way? This question> [Create a route by using points (pgRouting)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141487/create-a-route-by-)
  still unanswered makes me think is not.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  We use a single, focused question/ best answer model here, so multiple questions, questions soliciting opinions, and open-ended  questions are considered off-topic (take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for details).   Please **edit** your question to ask a single, focused question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know the routes you want to illustrate, I'm not sure pgRouting is the right tool for the job—I believe it intended to support questions involving routing where you have a number of alternate path options, and you want to identify the most optimal route, chiefly among driving scenarios. For example a shorter, yet "higher cost" route (a main road during rush hour, or a main road impeded by maintenance, etc.) might actually be slower than a longer, more complex path using side roads. Or a scenario where you need to make a number of stops along a route, so you want to take the shortest/most efficient route possible (i.e. the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)). At least that is my impression of the sort of situations pgRouting would be used to evaluate.

Perhaps there is something I'm missing, where if I understood some additional context, applying pgRouting to your project would make more sense.

Were you wanting to apply pgRouting merely to render known routes on a map, or were you wanting to approximate various flow metrics, like the potential speed of one leg vs. another leg of a route?

If you just want to render the routes on a map, the classical approach would be to create a [flow map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_map) by first creating a base map in something like [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) or [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/), then adding "flows" (arrows, where line widths correspond to magnitudes, and line colors are used for additional classifications) afterwards as a finishing step using a software like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/?lovefrom=konsebt.com) or [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP)—all of those are free software.

There's another side to this subject that's less technical, but which you should consider, and that is the level of accuracy you can legitimately and defensibly achieve with this sort of map. If you had actual ships' logs where daily/frequent navigation details could be plotted, then you could produce a highly detailed map with no problem defending the level of detail you chose to illustrate. But if all you really know are common route endpoints, currents, and winds, it's probably more appropriate to use a generalized level of detail, such as that afforded by ["great circle arcs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) (curved line on a mercator projection representing the shortest path on a sphere), [rhumb lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line) (straight line on a mercator projection showing constant bearing), and/or [bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (geographically irrelevant smooth curve), which you wouldn't need pgRouting to draw on your map.

Comment: Hi elrobis! Truth is that knowing the potential speed of the vessels would be cool, but for now I´ll be going with the "render routes on a map" approach (since seems easier and I´m a total noob).
I´ll have the accuracy subject on mind. Sometimes I know all sort of details, but sometimes I don´t.
I´ve thought about the "flow" in QGIS (and found a nice tutorial but the thing is that I do not know how to curve the lines so that become paths) let me know if you have any plugin in mind that may be useful. Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: You can use the spline plugin in QGIS to give your lines a curved effect.  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spline/